# Must declare the scalar variable at run time

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have an `IN clause` that I don't know how many values it will have until at run time that it reads them from my config file so with some code I managed to have something like this: ( Right side values I copied from the values of it at run time from breakpoint I put there):

```
string inClause = "@RefTableK0,@RefTableK1,@RefTableK2,@RefTableK3"
```

And then again by stepping though the code I have something like this as the `commandText`:

```
Select * From Blah
 Where A.GroupDescription = @GroupDescription And B.RefTable_K IN 
 (@RefTableK0,@RefTableK1,@RefTableK2,@RefTableK3)
```

And then to put the values in those params I do this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < RtkParamNames.Length; i++)
    {
        drCredentialingGroup.Parameters.Add(RtkParamNames[i], RtkValues[i]);
    }
```

Now if I hover over the paramters I have something like this in the picture below:

[image]

And after that when I call the Fill method I get that error:

```
Exception:Select Command Exception - Must declare the scalar variable "@RefTableK0@".
Exception:Must declare the scalar variable "@RefTableK0@".
Source:.Net SqlClient Data Provider
```

Comment: Make sure you have a value in `RtkValues[0]`, or pass `DBNull.Value`

Comment: From the exception it looks like you have a comma missing or in the wrong place.  What does the SQL statement say in the debugger?

Comment: @DStanley Do you want the CommandText? Or should I get it from somewhere else?

Comment: @Habib yes all of them do have values

Comment: Yes - make sure the commas are in the right place (unless either your SQL or error messages were not copied/pasted exactly)

Answer (score 0):

At the end had to manually remove the `"@"` signs, notice in the picture I had attached the values they had added did not have that `"@"` sign, so in the for-loop that I am assigning values, I added a `.Replace("@", "")` .